# How to extract gz files and rename to xml

Tags: python-2.7, file, extract, file-rename, gzip

I have approximately 130,000 gz files, each containing one file which needs to be renamed with a .xml extension in order to be viewed properly. For example, on gz file might be named `100.san.form.gz` and contain the file `100.san.form`, which needs to be renamed to `100.san.form.xml` to be viewed appropriately.

I am trying to write a script to unzip all of these files and then rename them appropriately, and read them into my program to parse.

Comment: Chop off the extension, add the new one, and extract into that file.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I'm new to Python. I've tried 

`with gzip.open(root_path, "rb") as f:    
    file_content = f.read()
    tree = ET.parse(file_content)`

but this gives me errors.